# Canon 6D self-timer triggered by the IR wireless remote. Is it possible?

Tags: remote, canon-6d

I have bought an infrared wireless remote (cheap simple one from eBay with a single button) for my Canon 6D. The camera has two modes for the self-timer and remote:

- 10sec/remote
- 2sec/remote

In case of using a remote, both options do the same thing: they take the photo immediately as triggered by the remote. I suppose the same goes with the wired remotes.

This is not what I want for group photographs that include me because in such case the photo shows my hand with the remote pointing the camera which looks awkward. It would be great if there was a delay of two seconds.

Is it possible to trigger the self-timer with the remote? I don't want to put 10s or 2s and then run to the group. How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not with your remote unless it has some switch you haven't mentioned.  There are a few different IR commands.   The ones I know about are one that does an instant shutter, one that does a two second delay.  Your remote appears to only do the instant shutter signal.

You will need a different remote that supports sending the two second delay signal.  Unfortunately the remote portion of the delay modes just means that it is accepting IR control and is unrelated to the actual delay of that mode.  (IR control also operates in bulb mode on some cameras.)  The RC-6 supports the two second delay mode.

Wired remotes actually emulate a shutter press and don't require being in the remote mode to operate, so they would be able to make use of the 2 second and 10 second delay modes of the camera itself.  This is not, however, how IR control works.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of it. But the good news is that I have found an older remote with multiple buttons, 2s among others, and it works!

Comment: @Filip - excellent, yeah, the IR commands have been the same for pretty much forever.